# Clustering adjacent counties

Tags: r

How do I cluster similar counties based on one or more variables to form clusters of contiguous counties - I have one record for each county. Ideally I would like to do this based on centroid lat/long or else adjacency matrix. I have both the lat/long and adjacency matrix already. The closest package I have found is SpatialEpi which would be great if I had count data. I have also tried using Mclust with lat/long as predictors to less than satisfactory or contiguous results. I have also tried CARBayes but this does not appear to be the right thing. Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

If you've got reasonably good spatial data (i.e. *not* like the data distributed in the **maps** package, or in `maptools::wrld_simpl`), you could use `rgeos::gTouches()` to form the adjacency matrix. (If you want a matrix indicating counties that are within some non-zero distance of one another, use `rgeos::gWithinDistance()` instead.)

For example, using county-level shapefiles downloaded [from here](http://www.gadm.org/) using the convenience function `raster::getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2)` and stored in a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` named "`gadm`", here's how I'd get the adjacency matrix for the counties of Rhode Island:

```
library(rgeos)

## Subset out just the counties in Rhode Island
RI <- gadm[gadm$NAME_1 == "Rhode Island",]
## Form their adjacency matrix
m <- gTouches(RI, RI, byid=TRUE)
## Add in counties' names along table edges
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- RI$NAME_2

## See that it works
RI
#            Bristol  Kent Newport Providence Washington
# Bristol      FALSE FALSE   FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
# Kent         FALSE FALSE   FALSE       TRUE       TRUE
# Newport      FALSE FALSE   FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
# Providence    TRUE  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
# Washington   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE      FALSE      FALSE

plot(RI, col=blues9[c(1,3,5,7,9)])
title("Rhode Island counties")
```

[image]